# IE7 CSS width:100% issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm working on a CSS template for a responsive %-based grid. I had it working with IE7 earlier and did something stupid, I guess, and now it's not working.

http://danmathisen.com/lightbase-css/

How it currently works:

Columns are percent based. So a 1/3 width column (`.col-1-3`) will be `width:32%` + `margin-left:1%` + `padding:1%`. This is heavily based on Chris Coyier's [Don't Overthink It Grids](http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/).

In modern browsers, the padding doesn't affect the div width. But in IE7 it does. So I have IE classes (`.lt-ie8`) that accomodate for the 1% padding. `.lt-ie8 .col-1-3 { width: 30%; }`. So 30% width + 1% margin-left + 2% padding left/right * 3 - 1% :first-child = 100%. Right?
Why doesn't that work in IE7?

Solutions:

I can use `behavior: url(/scripts/boxsizing.htc)` but hope to make this workable without.

Or use JS to calculate the width then subtract 1px. I think that would work, but it's not ideal.

Or settle with 99% width. Also not ideal.

I'd love a CSS-only solution. Any thoughts?

Comment: Glad to see someone's actually thoroughly researched their question first.

Comment: Part of your problem may be rounding errors. Because of this, it's generally not recommended to use percentage-based sizing, *especially* when mixing width/padding/margin.

Comment: @CharlesTian I've been searching for an answer for hours... that's what brings me here.

Comment: Chris Coyier himself says if you want to view his system in IE7, "You'll have to do something else =)". So don't fry your brain, try Twitter Bootstrap. It works for IE7.

Comment: What about forcing IE7 into quirks mode?  Older IEs used the wrong box model, which where the box-sizing property sorta comes from.  You should be able to get the old box model by feeding it a doctype that puts it in quirks mode.

Comment: @cimmanon - not a good idea. Unless you script the doctype into just IE7, all browsers will be in quirks mode. Best to just script the box model to work by using Modernizr or writing your own script, or fudging the CSS to compensate by using hacks (also, not a good idea).

Comment: @tahdhaze09 Isn't that what I said?  I figured when I said "forcing IE7 into quirks mode" and "feeding **it** a doctype" that it was obvious that I was implying that only IE7 would be switched to quirks mode.

Comment: Still not optimal. Just use Twitter Bootstrap, already works for IE7.

Comment: @tahdhaze09 twitter bootstrap is great, but too bloated. I hate having so much unused code. And sure, I can remove unused code, but I'm trying to create a minimalist template, without styling, that I can use for all projects (and that others will hopefully use).

Comment: That's cool. Try http://www.initializr.com/. Let's you pick what you need, leave out what you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but maybe you could try putting one div inside another, and have the padding or margins in the inner div? Something like this:

```
<div style="width:33%;padding:0;margin:0;">
<div style="padding:3%;margin:3%;">
Content here
</div>
</div>
```

Again, not sure if this will work, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I think this would work, but hoping to not create extra markup.
I'm looking for a solution that probably doesn't exist. Maybe I'm being too picky :)

Comment: Yeah, cross-browser compatibility for CSS styling can really been a pain sometimes. You're right though, this would create a lot of extra markup. If there is a perfect solution, I hope you find it. Good luck!